# Create custom pixel block size in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, raster

I'm using the new *IRawBlocks* in ArcGIS 10 from the adopted sample in ArcGIS 10 SDK help and I want to create a custom sized pixel block that feeds me a block of values column by column instead of a block.  So basically I'll be looping through each column in the raster.  Any ideas as I couldn't find anything in the documentation?

```c#
        IRawBlocks rwBlocks = (IRawBlocks)rb;
        IRasterInfo rsInfo = rwBlocks.RasterInfo;
        IPixelBlock pb = rwBlocks.CreatePixelBlock();

        // change pixel blocks size here?????

        // iterate through pixel blocks
        for (int pbXcursor = 0; pbXcursor < rsProps.Width; pbXcursor++)
        {
            string line = "";
            rwBlocks.ReadBlock(pbXcursor, 0, 0, pb);

            // iterate through cells in pixel block, should only be one pixel column
            for (int pbHeight = 0; pbHeight < pb.Height; pbHeight++)
            {
                object val = pb.GetVal(0, 0, pbHeight);//pbWidth, pbHeight);
                // etc
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try [IPixelBlock4.Create](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Create_Method/001q000001wv000000/) and set nCols to 1?

Comment: Just have but it seems to be reading from a weird location in the raster (haven't quite found where!).
                IPixelBlock pb = (IPixelBlock)rwBlocks.CreatePixelBlock();
                IPixelBlock4 pb4 = (IPixelBlock4)pb;
                pb4.Create(1, 1, rsProps.Width, rsInfo.PixelType);